# Silverstripe How to use Calendar on DateFields with custom form template?

Tags: silverstripe

I have created a custom form class and template for my form by following the instructions [here](http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/topics/forms#using-a-custom-template).

However I am having trouble with adding DateFields with calendars. Usually I just do something like this:

```
$dateField = new DateField ('DateRequired', 'Date Required');
$dateField->setConfig ('showcalendar', true);
```

I have tried the above code in my custom form however the page doesn't include any of the jquery ui scripts or css files for the calendar field.

So my question is how can I get the my custom form to include all the scripts and render the fields with the jquery ui calendars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I have worked it out. The code within the template that calls the fields needs to be changed from:

```
$dataFieldByName(DateRequired)
```

to:

```
$dataFieldByName(DateRequired).FieldHolder
```

Now all of the javascript is included within the page.

Answer (score 4):

actually the change of the template should not be necessary.

```
$dateField = new DateField('...');
$dateField->setConfig('showcalendar', true);
$dateField->setConfig('showdropdown', true);
$dateField->setConfig('dateformat', 'dd.MM.YYYY');
```

Comment: just a sidenote, there doesn't seem to be a 'showdropdown' option (any more?) in silverstripe 3.0.3